# Dll Import : Unable to find Entry Point "fnMultiply" in DLL "ImportDLL"

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am trying to use DLLImport for using Win32 dll method in C#.

Win32 dll C++
// .h file

```
#ifdef IMPORTDLL_EXPORTS
#define IMPORTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define IMPORTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the ImportDLL.dll
class IMPORTDLL_API CImportDLL {
public:
    CImportDLL(void);
    // TODO: add your methods here.
    int Add(int a , int b);
};

extern IMPORTDLL_API int nImportDLL;

IMPORTDLL_API int fnImportDLL(void);
IMPORTDLL_API int fnMultiply(int a,int b);
```

// .cpp file

// ImportDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ImportDLL.h"


// This is an example of an exported variable
IMPORTDLL_API int nImportDLL=0;

// This is an example of an exported function.
IMPORTDLL_API int fnImportDLL(void)
{
    return 42;
}

IMPORTDLL_API int fnMultiply(int a , int b)
{
    return (a*b);
}
```

Once i build this i get ImportDLL.dll

Now i create Windows Application and add this dll in debug folder and try to use this method using DLLImport

```
[DllImport("ImportDLL.dll")]
 public static extern int fnMultiply(int a, int b);
```

And I try to call this in C# 
 `int a = fnMultiply(5, 6);` // This line gives error Unable to find an entry point

Can any body tell what i am missing?
Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant This isn't an instance method. it is a regular public function in the DLL. Check the header decl. In fact, this is the stock "create me a DLL with exported symbols" project as spit out by VS. He's not trying to pinvoke an instance method; he's trying to wire up an exported function.

Comment: You are right, tripped up by the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are exporting a C function from a native DLL, you may want to use the [`__stdcall` calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (which is equivalent to `WINAPI`, i.e. the calling convention used by most Win32 API C-interface functions, and which is the default for .NET P/Invoke):

```
extern "C" MYDLL_API int __stdcall fnMultiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}

// Note: update also the .h DLL public header file with __stdcall.
```

In addition, if you want to avoid *name mangling*, you may want to [export using **.DEF files**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
e.g. Add a .DEF file to your native DLL project, and edit its content something like this:

```
LIBRARY MYDLL
EXPORTS
  fnMultiply @1
  ...
```

(You can use the command line tool **`DUMPBIN`**`/EXPORTS`, or a GUI tool like **[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)**, to check the actual name with which the function is exported from the DLL.)

Then you can use P/Invoke like this from C#:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
public static extern int fnMultiply(int a, int b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn off name mangling for the function your exporting. Should assist greatly. Alternative you could load the name mangled (there is a way to config the DllImport attribute to do this, so I hear, but I'm not a C# engineer, so I leave that to you to find if it exists).

```
extern "C" IMPORTDLL_API int fnMultiply(int a , int b)
{
    return (a*b);
}
```